# iOS/Parse query not finding string match in array

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am trying to query a PFObject that contains an array. I am looking to match a given NSString against any object within the PFObject's array of strings. According to http://blog.parse.com/2012/03/28/parse-supports-many-to-many-relations/, I can use whereKey:equalTo to look for matches within an array.

I have replaced the variable I would usually use with the string that I know to be in the array whose object I am querying. It is a character-for-character match. Yet the query returns no matches.

My code:

```
PFQuery *convosQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"convo"];
PFObject *currentUserFacebookID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"11808098"];
[convosQuery whereKey:@"nonUserFacebookIDs" equalTo:currentUserFacebookID];
[convosQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *convos, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *convo in convos) {
        NSLog(@"user/convo match found");
```

As I said, this returns no matches even though a PFObject of class "convo" contains for key "nonUserFacebookIDs" the value "[["11808098"]]".

What could be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this object have any ACLs that might be restricting reads to a subset of users?

Comment: I have not messed with ACL. The ACL for the object that should be found reads: {"*":{"read":true},"3rkf7hoxrD":{"write":true,"read":true}}

Comment: so as far as you can tell, this query for a string contained as an item in an array should work?

Comment: Yes. If you contact us through https://parse.com/help, we can debug further. Make sure to submit the support request using the "Contact us privately" link and mention this post.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned "[["11808098"]]". Does this mean an array of array containing a string? If so, it would not match the string you specified.

And BTW, though not related to your question, why did use the below line? Why should you assign a string to a PFObject?

```
PFObject *currentUserFacebookID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"11808098"];
```

~ Sunil Phani Manne

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. This was a long time ago when I was new to this, and I have no idea why I was assigning a string to a PFObject. And I see what you mean--that does look like an array of arrays, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hey, if you're knowledgable about Parse, you could maybe take a look at my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519195/how-to-check-parse-errors-when-using-findobjectsnserror-error-serialized-w . Cheers

Comment: When I click the above link, it says "The question was voluntarily removed by the user!".